# Creating data driven field on attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3

I want to create a Field on an attribute table, whose data will depend on another field within the same attribute table.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Please edit your question so it contains an example from your current attribute table, what the new field should look like and what you tried to far to create this field.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Have a look at virtual field, it may be what you want or at last will help you to clarify your need